# Using ClassNameMap or Record<string,string> type for passing styles from one component to another

Tags: react-hooks, material-ui, react-typescript

I am trying to pass more than one class styles from one component to another.
From Component A I am doing this,

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(() =>
    createStyles({
      label:{
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%",
        margin: "10px",
        backgroundColor: "white",
      },
    flex:{
    
    }
    })
  );
const styles=useStyles();

const getAllList=labelNames.map((name: string):ReactNode => {
 return (<Load
            label={name}
            classes={styles.flex} //here showing error under classes as "Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ClassNameMap<string> | undefined'."
            width={"100%"}
            onDataChange={(value: string, data: string): void => {
            }}
          />);
});
```

In Load component I declared like below,

```
interface Props {
  width: string;
  label: string;
  classes?: ClassNameMap;
  onDataChange: (selectedvalue: string, data: string) => void;
}
```

***"Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ClassNameMap | undefined'."***
above error I am getting in the line which I mentioned above. I am unable to find what need to do to fix the error. Any idea or suggestions will help me to resolve. Anyone have any idea about how to pass class styles to specific component.

Also, I need to pass more than one style as props.

Answer (score 0):

`ClassNameMap` and `Record<string, string>` are essentially the same.  Both are objects whose keys are strings and whose values are string class names.  If you want to refine the keys to just the allowed class names, `ClassNameMap<‘label’ | ‘flex’>` is the same as `Record<‘label’ | ‘flex’, string>`.

That’s not your issue.  Your problem is that the `Load` component expects an object of class names, but you are providing it with a single `string` class name `styles.flex`.  That’s why you get the error message:

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ClassNameMap | undefined'.

---

Based on what you are saying here:

> I need to pass more than one style as props

Probably you want to pass the entire object that you got from the `useStyles` hook.  Pass `classes={styles}` instead of `classes={styles.flex}`.